# Laravel search DB with multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, search, orm, eloquent

I have a table named `records` with a `user_id` column which links to a `users` table to set ownership.

I can correctly filter the records by `title` with a search string:

```
$records->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
```

But I'd like to return also the results containing the `users.firstname` and `users.lastname`, this is my (awful) join attempt:

```
$records->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'records.user_id')
        ->where('users.firstname', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('users.lastname', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');

// SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wait for a better answer I found a solution which works but **it's not optimal** since it involves one extra query to gather the author `user_id` and use it subsequently to query the `records`:

```
// Get the author ID
$author = DB::table('users')
                ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ",`firstname`,`lastname`) as `fullname`,id'))
                ->having('fullname', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                ->first();

// $author output:
stdClass Object
(
    [fullname] => John Doe
    [id] => 35
)

// Query the records using the gathered ID
$records->where('user_id', $author->id)
        ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
```

**Problems with this solution**: Apart from the extra query, if somebody searches for `John Doe` or `Some Title` the results are correct. But if searching for `John Doe Some Title`, nothing is shown because the author and the title can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set that also use the search parameter in your inner query:

```
$records->join('users', function($join) use ($search)
{
    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'records.user_id')
         ->where('users.firstname', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
         ->orWhere('users.lastname', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I stripped out the unnecessary code to keep it clean. I'll update the example to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to return result from Records by filtering with $search and also want to show users info for this records.
You can use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships).
Your model must be: 
In User model:

```
public function records()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Record::class);
    }
```

In Record model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

And in Controller:

```
   Record::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
           ->with('user')
           ->first();
```

Comment: I wish to return all the `records` for the search query `John Doe`, but the `firstname` and `lastname` are in the `users` table and not in the `records` table. Also, I'd like to return the records for `John Doe Some Title` too, where `John Doe` is in the `users` table and `Some Title` in the `records` table.